# How to check "Contains" in enum values with ignoring case c#?

Tags: c#, string, enums, enumeration

I need to check string values present in Enum or not using `Contains`.

```
public enum Days
{
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
    Sunday = 7
}

public class ResultObj
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

var filter = "Wed";
var dayList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days))
               .Cast<Days>()
               .Where(x => Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Days), filter))
               .Select(d => new ResultObj
               {
                   Id = (int)d,
                   Name = d.ToString()
               }).ToList();
```

If given "Wed" means, I need a dayList result as `{ Id = 3, Name = Wednesday }`.

If given filter as "Wednesday" means, I need a dayList result as `{ Id = 3, Name = Wednesday }`.

If given filter as "wednesday" means, I need a dayList result as `{ Id = 3, Name = Wednesday }`.

If given filter as "dnes" means, I need a dayList result as `{ Id = 3, Name = Wednesday }`.

If given filter as "xyx" means, the `dayList` count should be zero.

Comment: What does `Day.Monday.ToString()` return?

Comment: Sure you don't mean "StartsWith" instead of "Contains"? What would a string of "day" return?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, I need "Contains", not a "StartsWith".

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Wouldn't it just return every enum value? What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your `Linq` method chain a little bit, select a string values from array of `Enum` values and check that `Enum` name contains the filter (case insensitive). Then select a `ResultObj` and convert `Enum` value back

```cs
 var filter = "Wed";
 var dayList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Days))
     .Cast<Days>()
     .Select(x => x.ToString())
     .Where(x => x.Contains(filter, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     .Select(d => new ResultObj
     {
         Id = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(Days), d),
         Name = d
     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `Where` clause such as:

```
.Where(x => Enum.GetName(typeof(Days), x).ContainsCaseInsenitive(filter))
```

where `ContainsCaseInsensitive` is an extension method on string:

```
// adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15464440/5133585
public static bool ContainsCaseInsensitive(this string a, string b) =>
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(a, b, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0;
```